# what cms that can support more than one language?

Tags: content-management-system, translation

One of my clients asked me to integrate an open source CMS in her website.The challenge I have right now is that she wants the website to be bilingual. is there any cms that implements this feature? The content on each page should be displayed either in english or french and no automation translation(like google's or babel fish). only static content should be held in language configuration files.

Thanks for any help or idea.

Comment: For a bit more specifics, does she want two sites run off the same CMS with the same posts in different languages? Or does she want one-site with the ability for a user to switch between either language? (á la Wikipedia articles)

Comment: @David Antaramian, She want it to be "a la wikipedia", to switch languages and not 2 separate sites. this should make the site easily managed rather than having language specific site. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal, besides being considered the best php-based open source CMS, has multilingual support

"Internationalization: Build Multilingual Sites"
http://drupal.org/node/133977

Answer (score 4):

N2CMS can do that. It supports multi-sites on one installation, multi-language, templating, MVC. And it is a very developer-friendly, developed in C#.

- http://n2cms.com
- http://n2cms.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco does this, is FOSS and based on .NET.

http://umbraco.org/

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning the language, or platform but do you know any in php? thanks

Answer (score 1):

go for joomla it support multi lingual , use joom fish component

Comment: I dont want automated translation, I want my client to translate from one language to another language. Its more professional, and accurate. I guess joomla guys didnt take care of that issue, their solution is like having n sites for n languages. that is not good for some users.

Comment: I think JoomFish component will take care of your requirement , but I am not sure because I still didn't use it .

Answer (score 1):

According to [one of its FAQ's](http://plone.org/documentation/faq/translating-sites), [Plone](http://plone.org/), running the [LinguaPlone](http://plone.org/products/linguaplone) add-on can do this, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

MODXCMS.com does enable you to use lots of different languages on the same site!

They call it YAMS - Yet Another Multilingual Solution ---
[about YAMS on the MODX Forums](http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php/board,381.0.html)

Answer (score 1):

I say go with MODx CMS coupled with YAMS. Choose the Evolution release, not the Revolution. I just installed the YAMS and it's working like a charm.

The learning curve maybe a bit steep but it's worth every hour I spent learning it.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you looking for a translation memory/CMS or a CMS that integrates with a TM?
- How many languages are you looking to support?
- Any of the complicated ones? (HAT, for example)